# HTML5 resource storage

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I am making HTML5 game. I use indexedDB to store Images(about 50mb). It works great. But I want add my game to gaming site. Gaming site uses for games iframe. This works great in Chrome. But firefox has an error

```
TypeError: indexedDB is undefined
var request = indexedDB.open(dbName,BDversion);
```

Because  window.mozIndexedDB is null in  in iframe.

I found this info on mozila pages:

> It's important to note that IndexedDB doesn't work for content loaded
>   into a frame from another site (either `<frame>` or `<iframe>`. This is a
>   security and privacy measure and can be considered analogous the
>   blocking of 3rd-party cookies.  For more details, see bug 595307.

Any idea how to solve it?
P.S. Web SQL Database- seems will be unsupported soon

MY code:

```
 function RequestIm() {
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: BattleNs.addUrl +"/Battle/GetPicture",
                    data: "{ \"id\": \"111\",\"PictureID\":" + "\"" + ID + "\"" + "}",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    async: false,
                    success: function (Picture) {
                        returnpic = Picture;
                        // alert(UnitsInfoMass);
                        return returnpic;
                    }
                });

                Data = returnpic;
                var tempdata = { UniID: ID, Data: Data, DataVersion: DataVersion };
                var request = objectStore.put(tempdata);
                request.onsuccess = function (event) {
                    CountOfDBIterrations[Numer].ID = ID;
                    CountOfDBIterrations[Numer].Image.src = returnpic;
                    CountOfDBIterrations[Numer].Image.onload = function (e) {
                        CountOfDBIterrations[Numer].Loaded = true;
                         BattleNs.loadingCount++;
                          BattleNs.loadingCountChange();
                    };
                };
```

Answer (score 3):

IndexedDB is not the best place to store images. Look at changing your game to a Web App. You can include the images and other assets in the manifest and the browser will download them to the local PC. Your app can access them directly, and there's no need to unpack them from the DB.

More info [here](http://diveintohtml5.info/offline.html)

Comment: Hm, i it looks great. But i load my images with ajax. And I don't append them to dom. Do you know  what to do in this case?

Comment: I check dipper i found that indexedDb as  well  as manifest-cache store data in sqlite files. So it seems it isn't big difference